# Write a method called replace3sWith4s() that takes an integer array, and changes any element that has the value 3 to instead have the value 4

Tags: java, arrays

Write a method called replace3sWith4s() that takes an integer array, and changes any element that has the value 3 to instead have the value 4.

need to include a for loop aswell

```
void replace3sWith4s (int [] x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] == 3) {

        }
    }
}
```

heres my code at the moment what else do i need to do??

using java

Comment: You need to use Java and create code by your self.

Comment: You are so close. No you found the cells with 3, now write in a 4...

Comment: It seems like a homework. Doesn't it?

Comment: You're nearly there. Just figure out how to change a value of a variable and you got it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This site is best suited to specific questions and providing answers. It is NOT for pasting your homework unless you show what you've tried, what problems you're having, and what they're doing wrong. Please check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So close....

```
    if (x[i] == 3) {
        x[i] = 4;
    }
```

Comment: Now you are teaching: _Come to SO for every tiny little problem you have_. I expect about 128 other questions from OP today...

Comment: thanks how i not see that! ha need sleep

Comment: @whoAml: As I anticipated: [This is what happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646649/trouble-with-my-enhanced-for-loop) when you encourage users by answering such questions...

Comment: I haven't thought it will be that fast... You were right :|

Comment: I've created a monster!

Comment: @whoAmI: [The next](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647294/taking-interger-arrays)

Comment: @whoAmI: [It goes on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649418/for-loops-in-bluej)

Comment: I don't know about you, but I've downvoted every post. As you see, I'm not the only one answer him. I guess he will post more and we should downvote more...