# Trouble with my enhanced for loop?

Tags: java, foreach

so im having trouble understanding enhanced for loops..

Write a method called contains() that takes an array of integers and an integer value. The method should return true if the array contains the specified value, otherwise false.

```
boolean contains (int [] x, int y) {
    for (y : x) {

    }

}
```

i dont really get how they work i obviously need to return something?

Comment: Try to write it with a normal for loop first if you find it easier. You can then try to transform your working code to a for-each loop (and watch the number of characters in your code decrease).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to check whether the number `y` in contained within the array `x`, you should do the following:

```
boolean contains (int [] x, int y) {
    for (int i : x) {
       if (i == y) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This type of `for` loop is often called `for-each`. The `int i : x` basically means `Go through the loop 'x' and name the current variable 'i'`. Then if the current variable `i` is equal to the one that you are looking for (in your case - `y`) then `return true`.

Comment: That answers the question but I'm not sure it helps the OP...

Comment: @assylias +1. The OP must learn and not simply copy/paste the answer

Comment: Cheers helped heaps got the other two answers aswell

Answer (score 0):

enhanced for loop doesn't work without data type defined at left hand side of the colon(:) symbol.

```
for (int i : x)   // int(in this case) is necessary at left side and array type is necessary at right side
{

}
```

also to use user defined collection then you should have **Iterable** interface implemented to use foreach loop like you are using above. You will see these concept in Collection framework.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### First step: what is the algorithm?

You need to iterate over the items in the array, and check if one of them is `y`, the int you are looking for.

#### Second step: Use a normal for loop if it feels easier

I assume from your question that you are more comfortable with a normal for loop:

```
boolean contains (int [] x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { //loop over each item in the array
        if (x[i] == y) return true; //if the i-th item in x is y,
                                    //you are done because y was in x
    }
    return false; //you have not found y, so you return false here
}
```

#### Third step: transform it into a for-each loop

```
boolean contains (int [] x, int y) {
    for (int item : x) { //in this loop, item is x[i] of the previous code
        if (item == y) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Notes:

- In your code, you are reusing y inside the loop, which is not what you want: y is what you are looking for and you need to compare it to the content of x.
- the syntax of the for-each loop on an array is: `for (Type item : array)`. You can't omit `Type` by declaring the variable before the loop for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using a normal for loop you would write something like this:

```
boolean contains (int [] x, int y) {
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
         if(y == x[i] return true;
    }    
    return false;
}
```

With the enhanced loop, however, it can be simplified as follows.

```
boolean contains (int [] x, int y) {
    for (int k: x) {
       if(y == k) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It is just a minor convenience.

You might find the following useful: https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with