# Taking integer arrays

Tags: java, arrays

```
boolean isValidIndex (int [] x, int y) {
    if((y>=0) && (y<x.length)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;

    }
}
```

Write a method called `isValidIndex()` that takes an array of integers and an index, and returns true if the index is valid for the array. For example, if the array had 10 elements then `isValidIndex(array, 9)` would return True,but `isValidIndex(array, 10)` would return False,as would `isValidIndex(array, -1)`.

Here is my code. It works but apparently it can just be one statement. How can I do that?

Comment: You could rename `y` to index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything on the format `if <expr> then true else false`, can always be shortened to just `<expr>`. So, in your case:

```
boolean isValidIndex (int [] x, int y) {
    return (y >= 0) && (y < x.length);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The value of this expression: `((y >= 0) && (y < x.length))` is a boolean, so you can use it directly like this:

```
boolean isValidIndex (int [] x, int y) {
    return (y >= 0) && (y < x.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return directly:

```
return (y >= 0 && y < x.length);
```

Comment: isn't it `y > -1` or `y >= 0`, since Java starts indexing from 0

Comment: Indeed, forgot the '=' signal from asker's example

Comment: @Felype You can edit and correct your answer by clicking on the `edit` link just below your answer. I've done it for you.

Answer (score 1):

return ( y >= 0) && (y < x.length);

Answer (score 0):

Make your function as

```
boolean isValidIndex (int [] x, int y) {

return ((y>=0) && (y<x.length));

}
```

the following will evaluate to true or false and the same can be returned .