# FOR loops in BlueJ

Tags: java

I have this code and it works but not on different created worlds cause the length is different how can i fix this? a bit stuck

```
void moveRobot(){
    for(int x=1; x<=61; x++) {
        if(isSpaceInFrontOfRobotClear()) {
            moveRobotForwards();
        }
        else {
            turnRobotLeft();
            turnRobotLeft();
            turnRobotLeft();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with *BlueJ*.

Comment: i wrote the code in bluej

Comment: @JamesOliver: If the question is not editor-specific, the editor does not matter. Removed bluej tag.

Answer (score 1):

By passing in the length of the world as a parameter, and using that instead of 61. For example:

```
void moveRobot (int worldsize){
    for(int x=1; x<=worldsize; x++) {
        if(isSpaceInFrontOfRobotClear()) {
        moveRobotForwards();
        }
        else {
            turnRobotLeft();
            turnRobotLeft();
            turnRobotLeft();
        }

    }

}
```

Alternatively, if the problem is in moveRobotForwards, then moveRobotForwards needs to be made aware of the world's size in a similar fashion.